# SSRS VB Custom Code returning #Error

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a VB code that was used in Excel as macro. I want to use the same code in SSRS as a custom code but I get #Error as result. Here is the code

```
Public Function ErlangC(ByVal m As Integer, ByVal u As Double) As Double
    Dim d as Double
    Dim s as Integer
    Dim k as Integer

    d = PowerFact(m, u)
    s = 1
    For k = 1 To m - 1
        s = s + PowerFact(k, u)
    Next k
    ErlangC = d / (d + (1 - u / m) * s)
End Function

Public Function PowerFact(ByVal m As Integer, ByVal x As Double) As Double
    Dim s as Integer
    Dim k as Integer

    s = 0
    For k = 1 To m
        s = s + Math.Log(x / k)
    Next k
    PowerFact = Math.Exp(s)
End Function
```

And I have a text box in SSRS with expression

```
=Code.ErlangC(65,60)
```

When I run the report, the value in the text box is #Error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the data type of `s` variables from `Integer` to `Double`.

```
Public Function ErlangC(ByVal m As Integer, ByVal u As Double) As Double
    Dim d as Double
    Dim s as Double
    Dim k as Integer

    d = PowerFact(m, u)
    s = 1
    For k = 1 To m - 1
        s = s + PowerFact(k, u)
    Next k
    ErlangC = d / (d + (1 - u / m) * s)
End Function

Public Function PowerFact(ByVal m As Integer, ByVal x As Double) As Double
    Dim s as Double
    Dim k as Integer

    s = 0
    For k = 1 To m
        s = s + System.Math.Log(x / k)
    Next k

    PowerFact = System.Math.Exp(s)
End Function
```

It is not tested but should work.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: that was it! changing the Integer to Double helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this in Visual Studio with SSDT you can see the text of the error in the Error List pane. In this case the error is:

Warning 1   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. \asufsp20\Homes$\spwhite1.ASURITE\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\projects\Report Project1\Report Project1\Report1.rdl    0   0

So it's a math issue. I tried the function with other values and it worked, but it's probably not returning the intended answer.

Comment: You were right about it being a math issue. The function worked for smaller number. Answer from alejandro worked for me.